# Force focus ReactNative TextInput

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-textinput

I'm having trouble force focussing a react native TextInput field.
It's focused when the page loads with `autofocus={true}`.

But after blurring I would need to press the text input field, but that's hidden because of design reasons. Is there a way to `document.getElementById("myText").focus();` in react native that I can call after `onBlur()`?

Cheers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to assign the `TextInput` field to a `ref` like this:

`<TextInput ref={ref => (this.ref = ref)} />`

Then you can programmatically focus it by running `focus()` on it, like so:

`this.ref.focus();`

Here's a little Snack where I run the focus/blur function when pressing a button: 
https://snack.expo.io/@marcelkalveram/auto-focus-input-field-using-ref

It should be easy to replicate this for your navigation scenario.

In case you're using react-navigation, this is the part of the docs you'll be interested in: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle

Comment: Hmm I'm getting a ref is not defined error, I literally copied the code from your snack?

Comment: @RubenHamakers Sorry to hear that you're having issues. I just ran it on Android and iOS and it worked fine for me. Can you try again and paste the complete error message in here?